# Invalid recurrence rule?

Tags: php, curl, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Here is the payload that I'm passing to Google Calendar API using `cURL`:

```
["start"]=>
  string(25) "2019-07-01T00:00:00+08:00"
  ["end"]=>
  string(25) "2019-07-16T00:00:00+08:00"
  ["title"]=>
  string(20) "Google Sync Weekly 4"
  ["description"]=>
  string(20) "Google Sync Weekly 4"
  ["recurrence"]=>
  string(44) "RRULE=WEEKLY;UNTIL=2019-07-16T00:00:00+08:00"
```

And in my `new_event.php`, where I process this payload:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
            'summary' => $event['title'],
            'location' => !empty($event['location']) ? $event['location'] : '',
            'description' => $event['description'],
            'start' => array(
              'dateTime' => $event['start'],
              'timeZone' => 'Asia/Taipei',
            ),
            'end' => array(
              'dateTime' => $event['end'],
              'timeZone' => 'Asia/Taipei',
            ),
            'recurrence' => !empty($event['recurrence']) ? [$event['recurrence']] : [],
            'reminders' => array(
              'useDefault' => FALSE,
              'overrides' => array(
                array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
              ),
            ),
          ));
```

Here is the value:

```
["recurrence"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(44) "RRULE=WEEKLY;UNTIL=2019-07-16T00:00:00+08:00"
  }
```

I can't figure out what I got wrong here. Any hints?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works as expected:

```php
$event = [
  'start' => "2019-07-01T00:00:00+08:00",
  'end' => "2019-07-16T00:00:00+08:00",
  'title' => "Google Sync Weekly 4",
  'description' => "Google Sync Weekly 4",
  'recurrence' => "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20190716T000000Z",
];

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => $event['title'],
  'location' => !empty($event['location']) ? $event['location'] : '',
  'description' => $event['description'],
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => $event['start'],
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Taipei',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => $event['end'],
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Taipei',
  ),
  'recurrence' => !empty($event['recurrence']) ? [$event['recurrence']] : [],
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$service->events->insert('primary', $event);
```

The issue is, as the error message suggests, your recurrence rule is formatted incorrectly. Rules should be prefixed with `RRULE:` and must follow the rules laid out in [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5). Pay close attention to the sections regarding timestamps and timezones. A basic example of a properly formatted rule may be found in the "Creating recurring events" code snippet in the [API documentation site](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents).

You could also create a recurrence from the Calendar UI and fetch it via the API for other more tailored examples.

Comment: Was also able to discover this small typo on my own. Thanks!